# Fail to build sqlcipher with mingw

Tags: linker, openssl, mingw, sqlcipher

I have problem with linking OpenSSL to SqlCipher, it looks like every thing is set up correctly when compiling a simple OpenSSL demo:

```
gcc  -Wall -o ssl-demo testssl.c -lssl -lcrypto -lwsock32 -lgdi32
```

But when it comes to sqlcipher I get this message:

```
configure: Release set to 3.7.17
configure: Version number set to 3007017
checking whether to support threadsafe operation... yes
checking for library containing pthread_create... -lpthread
checking for crypto library to use... openssl
checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: Library crypto not found. Install openssl!"
```

Looking in the `configure.log`:

```
configure:10593: checking for crypto library to use
configure:10660: result: openssl
configure:10662: checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto
configure:10687: gcc -o conftest.exe -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL  -lgdi32 -lssl -lcrypto conftest.c -lcrypto  -lpthread  >&5
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa0c): undefined reference to `CreateDCA@16'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa19): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa2a): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa3a): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa50): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa5e): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa70): undefined reference to `GetObjectA@12'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xae1): undefined reference to `BitBlt@36'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaeb): undefined reference to `GetBitmapBits@12'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb42): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb49): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb53): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
k:/qt/qt4.8.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb5d): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:10687: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "sqlcipher"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sqlcipher"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.7.17"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "sqlcipher 3.7.17"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char HMAC_Init_ex ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return HMAC_Init_ex ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:10696: result: no
configure:10706: error: Library crypto not found. Install openssl!"
```

The command used to compile SqlCipher:

```
$ ./configure --enable-static=no --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lgdi32 -lssl -lcrypto"
```

I also tried to change the order of linking but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears configure is unable to locate your version of libcrypto.  Can you try adjusting the `LDFLAGS` in configure to include `-L/some/path/to/your/library`.

Comment: Still some error, the log shows: `configure:10687: gcc -o conftest.exe -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL  -L/ssl/lib -lgdi32 -lssl -lcrypto conftest.c -lcrypto  -lpthread  >&5
c:/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa0c): undefined reference to `CreateDCA@16' c:/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa19): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'`

Answer (score 0):

> configure:10687: gcc -o conftest.exe -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_OPENSSL  -lgdi32 -lssl -lcrypto conftest.c -lcrypto  -lpthread  >&5

As you can see `-lgdi32` goes before the second `-lcrypto` and it needs to go after. To force this, you have to add `LIBS="-lgdi32"` to your configure.

If you want to dig into it, see `./configure` line 10668 (version 3.7.17).